# It's a GET method, but why isn't it opening?

Tags: javascript, iframe, methods

Below is a request capture of a packet loaded via `<iframe>`.

```
GET https://example.com/Book/SeatDetail.asp?Code=23004325&Place=22000001&Seq=059&Grade=&Block=RGN001& HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe
Referer: https://example.com/Book/Seat.asp
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: pcid=165426879431606504; OAX=tEG052KaI3kADYn0; _fbp=fb.1.1654268794851.469197131; _trs_id=eY3267%3F40530237; _atrk_siteuid=8zCsQr1SL05ijOmg; imfs_pcid=948395927242341323; RegionCode=FX001; SAVEID=Y; _ACU124043=1663334614224606514.1663334614224.1.0.606514TB7WGOMQKVE6Y.0.0.0.....; __utmz=41825914.1668791810.13.9.utmcsr=ticket.interpark.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; tourGUID=99190970-68aa-4554-8c3b-74e4a75cb1e7; _BS_GUUID=6aQfoD68fbf5t2kVXxPUMeymXIboncQunHJMlPVA; _TRK_AUIDA_13778=5b7c47437529c00b0902091a52af8001:1; TR10125305318_t_uid=49125550017099688.1670070741907; _SHOP_PC_ID=20230213012123898443344; __utma=41825914.839734280.1654268795.1676308218.1676980975.22; interparkID=bR0PdJzfu6aEZHFKaEYJBg%3D%3D; interparkSaveID=EgA3gykiaM%2B9Z0w8SN0fzQ%3D%3D; _gid=GA1.2.201996984.1689082042; sector=ticket; PrivacyCertify=gd%2BzEjhN0HbDaf%2FwK7Uu8w%3D%3D; alMemNm=67CV7IiY7ZiE; IMem%5FNO=KDmv85qaRn1UV6mbNY%2BlNw%3D%3D; TSecLogin=z9QWA27p67NF45ZDtiwG8jT4sNLL5CZr4Wz1K%2FUfai8%3D; TKLogin=; _trs_sid=G%5B646743574674%5Bg%5B1045%3D62712015; ab.storage.deviceId.cd97b079-ff05-4967-873a-324050c2a198=%7B%22g%22%3A%22b39f5a83-5626-f2b1-6fa3-db146f9f88ac%22%2C%22c%22%3A1649427743318%2C%22l%22%3A1689183031344%7D; ab.storage.userId.cd97b079-ff05-4967-873a-324050c2a198=%7B%22g%22%3A%22KDmv85qaRn1UV6mbNY%2BlNw%3D%3D%22%2C%22c%22%3A1688727149461%2C%22l%22%3A1689183031345%7D; _ga_9Z7ZBRRQK6=GS1.2.1689183036.7.0.1689183036.0.0.0; id_token=eyJraWQiOiJQSHhjWHlZcDdjUm1mTFFQOTFVS055MnFsXzNyVUZINDBrRm9QWlJTWkJFIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.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.JxoTbO3jxaABuM16bgAoI6RgizT8wn6QzKCllW3k_EPCRbTx6WcAoSw2qMu26w00pIskRn4U3r-l43dnaVkfMK0wXzwIW-v9ZjgXnSf782QqClz-hnQTnmHC9wu59WQhLxRpE3os1mu03dBFr-dWdk2S7vZdD8LwmQjzEb6LJjlRO4yRKoMcT5lvnZCQO52fe9kF1BaNWN10NYQFqb65ERPj_DldOT9uA9MZvD0nw2eFCj19_9aDwgt42kG2AHfTzX7TZM_dfY_DlJ6PW_80fJ3rzRmn88E_aRWUpCV_stE1naGqEUVHWwdVt9AmOzAKHSTZDtHaiGjXcaDUVy3svA; idt_iss=1689183041000; IEGS_GUIF=12%242%2424%24; iaf=oM%2BHsf0GM7kU5S%2FRy%2FxU1GdnBPEnWj0fXE9bx7Wa58S%2BRrdWPQhiiIEvYbm1av7G; memRealName=PuId6ZqM6WUdmWO3u8SRQQ%3D%3D; tempinterparkGUEST=KDmv85qaRn1UV6mbNY%2BlNw%3D%3D; interparkSNO=do4v4fFWlLpGxG8VZbbNtbx3oxuUwDoKjdOohxSBoJw%3D; siteAgree=YYYY; interparktime=1689183041; TMem%5FNO=TqfbhfHSR1pU8Mxi%2FVbm%2Bg%3D%3D; MemHash=6772c650bfeacfa4c5d091a3e6f6d417; HMem%5FNO=wwhHKo1AKpxF4Sa05w3r2w%3D%3D; _ga_0NYYVHZMWJ=GS1.1.1689183036.67.0.1689183041.55.0.0; TodayGoodsList=23004325,23006740,23008851,23007291,23007875,23007874,23009501,23009151,23006907,23006909; _trs_flow=https%3A%2F%2Fticket.interpark.com%2F; _gat_UA-93889457-1=1; cto_bundle=heEGNl9Pd015ODJ3Y2RrRTJxaEUzREdVb2xUWTJ6Y1NsdFglMkZidFQzJTJCR3ZtS0prWEJ0RGdXeW96c1NCcGRWbzJKMFlUQlR1TFBZbHRSMFB3STJiSVBZNXYyN1ZmNnNNWCUyRklyY1JEVFlhRFZLM3JheXNXRDlQeGVvV3hWc3Bnb0dGNlV5V3BDMUdXSW5JbXdFRDYlMkZ0UzRoZlppdyUzRCUzRA; nclab=TICKET-PC-tp_bridge-bridge_product-C; interparkstamp=6547104275496215481986101286642901; _ga_4SKTL7E8Q8=GS1.1.1689183031.279.1.1689184513.36.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.839734280.1654268795; ab.storage.sessionId.cd97b079-ff05-4967-873a-324050c2a198=%7B%22g%22%3A%22ea1d6845-090c-6f33-eb34-4410bea6b0b9%22%2C%22e%22%3A1689186313730%2C%22c%22%3A1689183031343%2C%22l%22%3A1689184513730%7D
```

The request method is marked as GET, so I pressed the address next to it, and it was not blocked with an alert.

I requested it through the `<iframe>` in the source as it was, and it worked fine.

What's the reason? I want to know why I was blocked even though I requested it as get. What is the function of `<iframe>`?

Comment: The function of `<iframe>` is to embed one web page inside another. It's possible for a web page to use header tags that prohibit being shown in an iframe.